# How to repeatedly alternate between two (or more) commands?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, for, watch

I'd like to repeatedly iterate over, alternate between, and/or cycle through multiple commands; in a kind of pattern or loop. The desired end result could be thought of as not totally unlike `watch`.

I've been experimenting with variations of this basic formula; but something is missing, wrong, or otherwise:

```
for x in {1..60}; 
do 
    <first command> && 
    sleep 1 && 
    <second command>; 
done
```

I think it's just reiterating (`do`ing) the `<first command> &&` sixty times, then all subsequent operations just one time, like normal. I've tried a few different things; like using `{`braces`}`, `'`quotes`'`, `"`quotes`"`, and so on; in an attempt to group commands together, without success.

Comment: The `&&` may be a problem, since it requires a successful exit status.  Do you want it to finish the first command, *then* if the first command was successful, do a `sleep 1`, or  have it `sleep 1` while the first command completes in the background regardless of exit codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright, I think I figured it out.

I think I just need to add another `&& sleep 1` between the `<second command>` and `; done`.

Something like:

```
for x in {1..60}; 
do 
    <first command> && 
    sleep 1 && 
    <second command> &&
    sleep 1; 
done
```

Comment: That should have no effect on whether the second command completes, unless perhaps the two commands have some undisclosed resource conflict.

Comment: @agc *"..should have no effect on whether the second command completes.."* This is an accurate statement. I don't think that was ever an issue, though.

Comment: Why don't you just do a `set -e` at the beginning  & dispense with all those `&&` ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma I'm not familiar with what that is, or how it works. I'm just using what I've learned thus far, the way I understand it. Although, I don't really find the use of operators, like `&&`, `||`, and `;` to be a hassle or anything; I kind of like the visual cues.

Comment: @RakeshSharma But, by all means, feel free to elaborate on your idea.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    for x in {1..60}; 
    do echo "1" &&
    sleep 1 &&
    echo "3"; 
    done
```

This also works for me:

```
    for x in {1..60}; 
    do echo "1";
    sleep 1;
    echo "3"; 
    done
```

What are your other two commands?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to put each command into an element of an array:

```
commandlist=('echo "hello"' 'echo "howdy"')
```

And then iterate through it:

```
for x in {1..10}; do 
    index=$((x%2))  # % takes the modulus (or remainder) of integer division
    ${foo[$index]}
    sleep 1
done
```

`${foo[0]}` expands to `echo "hello"`, which is then executed.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in bash or zsh in emacs mode via <kbd>control+o</kbd>:

```
$ set -o emacs
$ echo a
a
$ echo b
b
$ echo c
c
```

Then use history navigation to get to the `echo a` (or appropriate) command, then mash <kbd>control+o</kbd> a bunch of times. The commands from where you navigated to the most recent one should be repeated and looped over again for each <kbd>control+o</kbd>.